django & nginx & uwsgi deployed service not working
I have an issue with django & nginx & uwsgi, deployed service suddenly stopped with no reason few hours ago, so I don't know where to start debugging. (I'm very new to backend eng.)
When I run the virtual environment using py manage.py runserver it works and 'sudo systemctl status uwsgi' 'sudo systemctl status nginx' both are active. But when I try to open the admin site with designated url, it doesn't respond and shows timeout error.
there are no problems in ssl certifications(valid until next month), and port is opened normally (80, 443). When I tried ssh connection to the server via vscode it also worked.
where should I find the problem? please help
